# How to disable video recording option when opening camera

Tags: java, android, video

How to disable video recording option when device camera is opened in android?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to achieve that.Use a surfaceView to open only a camera view and broadcast only camera to capture an image or you can tell me what your mainly want to do?Your using default intent to launch camera??or your using camera api for that?